# Jquery toggle the visibility of a UI element, but make it invisible if no part of that div is clicked

Tags: jquery, toggle

This is similar to the facebook and google notification buttons, where you click on them and pops up a window, and closes if you click that button again or if you click on any part that isn't part of the notification div.

My problem is I can't find an event for unclicking an object or clicking out of it.

This is what I have now, where you can only close what pops up if you re-click the button.

```
notifycounter.click(function() {
    return imagepanel.toggle();
});
```

This is what I've tried, but neither events fire:

```
notifycounter.focusin(function() {
  return imagepanel.toggle();
});
notifycounter.focusout(function() {
  return imagepanel.hide();
});
```

notify counter is an h3

image panel is an img

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
notifycounter.click(function(e) {
    imagepanel.toggle();
    e.stopPropagation();//this will stop the event bubbling
});

$(document).click(function(){
   if(imagepanel.is(':visible')){
      imagepanel.hide(); 
   }
});
```

You can optimize it little more like this.

```
notifycounter.click(function(e) {
    imagepanel.toggle();
    e.stopPropagation();//this will stop the event bubbling

    if(imagepanel.is(':visible')){
        $(document).one('click.imagepanel', function(){
             imagepanel.hide(); 
        });
    }
    else{
        $(document).unbind('click.imagepanel');
    }
});
```

Comment: Wrap the .hide() inside a `if( imagepanel.is(':visible') ){` could help?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan - Yes, it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind to the `document` element and check if the target of the event is the correct element:

```
$(document).on('click', function (event) {
    if (event.target == 'my-element-id') {
        //the element was clicked-on
    } else {
        //something other than the element was clicked-on
        $('#my-element-id').hide();
    }
});
```

You can also use `event.stopPropagation()` to stop the event from propagating up to the `document` element: http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

```
$('#my-element-id').on('click', function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
$(document).on('click', function () {
    $('#my-element-id').hide();
});
```

Only clicks on elements other than `#my-element-id` will trigger the `document`s click event handler.

Note that `.on()` is new as of jQuery 1.7 and in this case can be replaced with `.bind()` if you are using an older version: http://api.jquery.com/on

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and the nice explanation.